# neo4j count matches made within list

Tags: neo4j

So I am using neo4j to get a list of nodes related to a given input. That input is in the form of tags and so I want to return all nodes that exist with some number of tags from those specified. I have the query for this working however I was hoping to integrate *how many* tags were matched along side this query. This will allow me to weight the results that have more shared tags higher than those with only one or two tags.

The query I am working with right now is:

```
MATCH(n) WHERE any(x IN ["im-a-tag", "test2"] WHERE x in n.tags) return n
```

and so say I have 2 nodes `a{tags:["im-a-tag", "not-important"]}` and `b{tags:["im-a-tag", "test2"]}`, how would I return `a{..., weight: 1}  b{..., weight: 2}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on the answer given by @nimrodserok, you can try this as well:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH size(apoc.coll.intersection(n.tags, ["im-a-tag", "test2"])) as weight, n
WHERE weight > 0
RETURN { properties: properties(n), weight: weight }
```

In this query, we first calculate the size of the intersection (weight), then we filter the nodes, where the weight is greater than 0. This query will be a bit more optimized, as we are performing intersection only once, as compared to twice in the other queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `APOC`, you can use `apoc.coll.intersection` with `size`:

```
MATCH(n) WHERE any(x IN ["im-a-tag", "test2"] WHERE x in n.tags) 
WITH size(apoc.coll.intersection(n.tags, ["im-a-tag", "test2"])) as weight, n
return n, weight
```

Or if you want the result as a JSON:

```
MATCH(n) WHERE any(x IN ["im-a-tag", "test2"] WHERE x in n.tags) 
WITH size(apoc.coll.intersection(n.tags, ["im-a-tag", "test2"])) as weight, n
return {properties: properties(n), weight: weight}
```